# 16.04 17.03.2017 Latest update a disaster

Tags: boot, icons

Good day

I have just loaded the latest 16.04 updates and the screen icons went from a normal size to one for giants. Sys settings screen display says it can not
read the screen to adjust. I have lost my internet with a different style
of menu.(this sent on my laptop with 16.10).
Tried booting back a couple of steps on recovery but makes no difference.
help please.
I am quite ok with pcs as I have been using for many years but am not very 
familiar with the inner workings of Ubuntu as I am well over my 3 score and 10 and disinclined to load another program in since my DOS days.

thank you